# Select certain values from one column base on a condition and change the value in that column

Tags: r

I have a de-identified dataframe "data". The age in the first row was changed if the age was over 60. So 61 would be 300 and 62 is 301, and so on. I would like to convert the age back to the real age for those over 60s. FYI, the rows are more than 50,000. I tried with

```
  for (i in length(data$age) & data$age[1]>299) {
    data$age[i] <- data$age[i]-299
   }
```

that did not give an error but the values were not change either. 
Here is a dummy data. Could anybody give me some advice? Thanks!

```
age gender  salary
19   1       600
19   0       700
35   1       800
30   0      1000
45   1       900
60   0       800
300  1      1000
302  0       900
309  1       700
```

Comment: No need for loops, try `data$age <- ifelse(data$age >= 300, data$age-300, data$age)`

Comment: Sorry @zx8754, the result of those over300 solved, but the min value of the column changed to 0, why?

Comment: It should be `data$age <- ifelse(data$age >= 300, data$age-300+61, data$age)`

Comment: @zx8754 thanks. now it returns the right answers. I realized the reason as well.  Thanks:)